Pandas Setting a single index for multiple rows in a dataframe
I have a dataframe that looks like this:




Column A
Column B
Column C




1
Group 1
B1
C1


2
Group 1
B2
C2


3
Group 2
B3
C3


4
Group 2
B4
C4


5
Group 3
B5
C5


6
Group 3
B6
C6



I want to group the values of Column A without aggregating the values of the other columns and transform the Column A in the index of the dataframe. The final dataframe needs to look like this:




Column B
Column C




Group 1
B1
C1



B2
C2


Group 2
B3
C3



B4
C4


Group 3
B5
C5



B6
C6



Anyone knows how can i do this? Thanks in advance

df.set_index('Column A'), optionally: df.set_index('Column A').sort_index()
